# Item ordered by category

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have these in my database.  Each item is in some category, and I want to display all items in the category ordered along with the category id.  Something like this:

```
1 
Expresso
Americano
2
Capuchino
```

Here is my seed code:

```
  {content: "expresso", price: "29000", category_id: 1},
  {content: "Americano", price: "29000", category_id: 1},
  {content: "Capuccino", price: "35000", category_id: 2},
```

This is the controller action that performs the query:

```
def menu
  @items = Item.order('content ASC')
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your view:

```
 <%- Category.includes(:items).order('categories.id').each do |category| %>
    <%= category.id %>
    <%- category.items.each do |item| %>
      <% = item.content %>
```

Comment: can you remove `N+1` queries from here?? by using `Category.includes(:items).order("categories.id")` in controller action

Comment: undefined local variable or method `categories' for #<#<Class:0x000000052d84a8>:0x000000057b9dc8>

app/views/categories/menu.html.erb:11:in 
Some error here, do i have to write something more in the controller file? @Andrey Deineko

Comment: @vicnoob I used `haml` syntax, and you have `erb`, that's why you have problem. Let me change it to `erb` - give my a minute

Comment: i think the problem here is not the syntax but the controller doesnt understand what i mean

Comment: It has nothing to do with controller, just put the code to the view and you're done.

Comment: @vicnoob Actually in post previously @Andrey Deineko directly fires queries for each category in loop for fetching items for each category so it will fires queries continuously on db so it slow down your process and also increase traffic on db. using `includes` we can `eager_load` the record so it will fetch all records in one stroke from db. you can refer http://blog.arkency.com/2013/12/rails4-preloading/

Comment: U guys all master, do u have tutorial on utube or skype that i can ask later :D

Comment: @vicnoob did that help or do you still have issues?

Comment: @vicnoob please be sure to accept the answer if it solved your issue :)

Comment: 1 more thing that im working on other html, using nav bar, i have 
    <% @categories.each do |category| %>
   <li role="presentation"  style="margin:2px; border-radius: 10px; background-color: #CAE5E8; text-transform: uppercase;"> <a data-toggle="tab" href="#<%= category.id %>"> <%= category.content %> </a> </li>
 <% end %>

How do i put the first tab active ( default show)

Comment: @vicnoob I'm a backend guy, so I do 0% of front, unfortunately can't help here